# Cant Compile JW Player

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder, jwplayer

I am trying to compile jw player and can't get it. I just added secure token and that is all I changed. I am using ant to compile and have flex sdk 3.

root@server1 [/home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5]# ant -buildfile build/build.xml  build-lib
Buildfile: build/build.xml

build-lib:

clean-dir:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/bin-release/sdk
     [exec] Loading configuration file /home/hold/compile/flex_sdk_3/frameworks/flex-config.xml
     [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/HTTPMediaProvider.as: Error: Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. Video (from /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/Video.as) and flash.media:Video (from /home/hold/compile/flex_sdk_3/frameworks/libs/player/10/playerglobal.swc(flash/media/Video)) are available.

```
 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/VideoMediaProvider.as: Error: Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. Video (from /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/Video.as) and flash.media:Video (from /home/hold/compile/flex_sdk_3/frameworks/libs/player/10/playerglobal.swc(flash/media/Video)) are available.

 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/RTMPMediaProvider.as: Error: Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. Video (from /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/Video.as) and flash.media:Video (from /home/hold/compile/flex_sdk_3/frameworks/libs/player/10/playerglobal.swc(flash/media/Video)) are available.

 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/HTTPMediaProvider.as: Error: Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. Video (from /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/Video.as) and flash.media:Video (from /home/hold/compile/flex_sdk_3/frameworks/libs/player/10/playerglobal.swc(flash/media/Video)) are available.

 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/VideoMediaProvider.as: Error: Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. Video (from /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/Video.as) and flash.media:Video (from /home/hold/compile/flex_sdk_3/frameworks/libs/player/10/playerglobal.swc(flash/media/Video)) are available.

 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/RTMPMediaProvider.as: Error: Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. Video (from /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/Video.as) and flash.media:Video (from /home/hold/compile/flex_sdk_3/frameworks/libs/player/10/playerglobal.swc(flash/media/Video)) are available.

 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/HTTPMediaProvider.as(26): col: 24 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Video.

 [exec]             protected var _video:Video;
 [exec]                                  ^

 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/HTTPMediaProvider.as(85): col: 17 Error: Call to a possibly undefined method Video.

 [exec]                     _video = new Video(320, 240);
 [exec]                                  ^

 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/VideoMediaProvider.as(21): col: 24 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Video.

 [exec]             protected var _video:Video;
 [exec]                                  ^

 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/VideoMediaProvider.as(60): col: 17 Error: Call to a possibly undefined method Video.

 [exec]                     _video = new Video(320, 240);
 [exec]                                  ^

 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/RTMPMediaProvider.as(59): col: 28 Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Video.

 [exec]         private var _video:Video;
 [exec]                            ^

 [exec] /home/hold/compile/trunk/fl5/src/com/longtailvideo/jwplayer/media/RTMPMediaProvider.as(94): col: 26 Error: Call to a possibly undefined method Video.

 [exec]             _video = new Video(320, 240);
 [exec]                          ^

 [exec] Result: 12
```

Comment: I don't know much about JW Player; but it doesn't look like a Flex Application; are you trying to use it in a Flex Application or convert it to a Flex Application?  Based on the error "cannot resolve multiname reference" it sounds like you are having path issues; where the Flex compiler doesn't know where to find code.

Comment: ok well i don't know much about flex just thought that following their instructions to secure jw player would be easy.

Comment: I'm not sure what instructions you are following; but that sounds like important information you may consider adding to your question.

Comment: http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/trunk/fl5/README.txt

Answer (score 0):

you need Flex SDK 4.1 to compile Jw Player.